# S Trap conversion - not enough room

Tags: drain, sink, venting

I'm getting some gurgling from my kitchen sink which I think is due to this S trap. No ventilation.  I want to convert to a P trap, and bring an AAV into the situation but with the current PVC layout I don't know if it's doable.  I started looking at this [flexible pipe solution](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SnappyTrap-Snappy-Trap-Drain-Kit-Double-Bowl-Kitchen-Sinks/1003205128) as a way to change the angle and give me more space to pipe into the drain.

Is that the way to go? Or is there a better solution?

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong, but a P-trap is for a wall exiting drain. You've got a floor exit, so no matter what you do, you'll end up with an S-trap of some sort. Why not just cut a T into the vertical pipe after the trap and insert your vent there. That's effectively what you'd be doing with the fancy flexi pipe anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, as @FreeMan suggests, you won't have a true P-trap unless you run a new vent line up through your roof (or connect to an existing roof-vent.)  Adding an AAV is a good work-around.  An AAV (or any vent) goes downstream of the trap.  The vertical section is a good place for it.  When you add the AAV, configure it with a small vertical riser so the AAV itself is at least a few inches above the trap's water line.

Comment: There is a photo in this article that shows the proper P-trap, vent, drain with sanitary tee set up, scroll down to "the right way".   - https://www.familyhandyman.com/article/never-connect-a-trap-to-a-vertical-drain-like-this/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible "other and better" solution from IPC (which may or may not be what your local code is based on - mine is, but this specific section is then banned in the local modifications) is to increase the size at the downturn - see [section 917](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-9-vents#IPC2018_Ch09_Sec917).

By making the downpipe a size larger than the input from the sink, the downpipe cannot be filled to the point of siphoning. I think 2" is called out in that section as currently written, and your typical kitchen sink is 1-1/2"

However, that may be as much work as just moving the drain connection to the wall, with a vent, which I'd argue is better. Certainly more work than installing an AAV, *but I'm biased against AAVs since they are prone to fail, and when they fail, they stink, so I will go to considerable effort to get a real vent in place rather than use one.*

For "Tee and AAV", flip the sink connections so the tailpiece is on the left, into a P-trap, into the **side** opening of a Sanitary Tee on top of the drain standpipe, and extend the AAV from the **top** of the Tee up as high as you can get it under the counter. Maintain 1/4" per foot slope on the "horizontal" runs towards the drain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, so you would suggest piping it something like this?

[image]

Comment: The vent would be coming from the top of the tee, not the side. You would use a sanitary tee, not a the tee you have shown. The P-trap would feed into the side of the tee, the vent out the top and the drain out the bottom.

Comment: You have used the answer field inappropriately. **The answer field is for answers**. Add additional info or photos to the Question.  Please take the tour so you know how to participate here.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour